# How to add custom definitions in header file flex lexer?

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I was writing a reentrant lexer using flex. To pass additional information about the matched token, I was using `yyextra` like this:

```
// my_lexer.h

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef enum {
    NUMBER, STRING;
} lex_token_type;

typedef struct {
    char* match;
    bool file_end;
} lex_token_extra;
```

```
%{
// my_lexer.l

#include <string.h>

#include "my_lexer.h"  // this line is being copied into 'my.lex.c' but not into 'my.lex.h'
%}

%option 8bit fast batch
%option reentrant
%option warn nodefault
%option yylineno
%option noyywrap
%option extra-type="lex_token_extra *"
%option outfile="my.lex.c"
%option header-file="my.lex.h"

%%

[0-9]+ {
    yyextra->match = strdup(yytext);
    return NUMBER;
}

["][^"]*["] {
    yytext[yyleng-1] = '\0';
    yytext += 1;
    yyextra->match = strdup(yytext);
    return STRING;
}

%%
```

The problem is, the line `#include "my_lexer.h"` is copied only into `my.lex.c` but not into `my.lex.h`. Hence I'm facing problems with the generated declaration `#define YY_EXTRA_TYPE lex_token_extra *` in `my.lex.h`. Is it possible to include corresponding header into generated header automatically? without me copying that line into header after it gets generated!

This is the error when I try to compile:

```
my.lex.h:239:23: error: unknown type name 'lex_token_extra'

                       ^
my.lex.h:256:20: note: in expansion of macro 'YY_EXTRA_TYPE'

                    ^
```

Comment: You could use `%option extra-type="struct lex_token_extra *"` in my_lexer.l and define the `struct lex_token_extra` type in my_lexer.h.

Comment: @IanAbbott That's what I'm doing. In addition to that, I'm using typedef to make it look neat. I removed typedef and checked. But the result is same error..

Comment: OK, my previous suggestion would cause `struct lex_token_extra` to be declared in a function parameter list, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Couldn't you just put `#include "my_lexer.h"` before `#include "my.lex.h"` in any .c file that includes the latter?

Comment: Yes. I'm doing that for now. But it feels somewhat unnatural. Dependencies of header file must be contained within it, not something that a user of it should be aware of!!